# apache conditional regex fails to match

Tags: regex, apache, apache2.4

I'm trying to figure out why the conditional regex never matches in apache, does it not work? 

`<If "%{HTTP:MY-Header} =~ /(.+)/">`

It *should* match since `(.+)` literally matches everything, but the code inside of the if block doesn't occur, so it is not matching. I've also tried `m#(.+)#` as well, but it also doesn't work. Is there something that I'm missing? Replacing `=~` with `!~` makes the code in the if block execute...

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem with `<If>` and regex trying to allow access to a protected directory only from elsewhere on my website.  `<If>` only seems to work for literal strings (ie. without any regex).

Eg. putting this in your protected directory's .htaccess file:

```
<If "%{HTTP_REFERER} != 'https://example.com/valid_subdir'" >
    Require all denied
</If>
```

will block all access from anywhere other than
https://example.com/valid_subdir
If that is what you want, fine - but it's too restrictive in most cases, eg. an attempted access from
https://example.com/another_subdir
will fail.  As it will if 'www.' is prepended, or the site becomes plain 'http' - either of which could happen if the hosting platform changes.

I've got round it by setting an environment variable and verifying access via `<RequireAll>`.  It's clunky, yes, but that is sadly the case with a lot of Apachese..

Put this is in the protected directory's .htaccess file (NB. You still have to misspell 'Referer'):

```
SetEnvIf Referer example\.com\/ isgood
# You can also stop bots with the following:
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "bot|crawl|spid|slurp|cloud|admant|ltx|qwant" bad_bot

<RequireAll>
    Require env isgood
# the next line will throw out bots, even if they munge the 'Referer'
    Require not env bad_bot
</RequireAll>
```

If a legitimate user clicks the link on https://example.com/any_page (or [www.example.com/any_page](http://www.example.com/any_page), or on http://example.com/any_page), they get to the protected directory.  Any attempt to access that directory from elsewhere will get an Error 403.

HTH